# getLine() returns newline and no data

Tags: c++, file, stream

I have the following code:

```
    const char *fn = fileName.c_str();
    std::ifstream file (fn);
    std::vector<std::string> value(20000);
    int i = 0;
    while ( file.good() )
    {
        getline ( file, value[i] );
        i+=1;
        std::cout << value[i]<< std::endl;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
```

The program reads the whole file, I know this because the correct number of indexes are printed. However there is no data, just a new line before each printing of "i". This is a file that I have saved from excel in windows and am reading in Linux - Is this my issue? What happened to my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is no data, just a new line before each printing of "i".

Because you increment `i` before accessing `value[i]`.

Incrementing `i` **just after** accessing `value[i]` solves the problem of missing data.

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r340YdGKN6ijWwVZ)

Comment: More precisely, `i` is incremented between the writing and reading of `value[i]`. (Moving the increment up a line should also fix the output, albeit at the cost of `value[0]` being unused.)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Sorry, I was simply fixing the logic error apparent.

However, here is an ideal version of reading lines of a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file {"test.txt"};
    std::vector<std::string> values;

    std::string temp;

    while (getline(file, temp)) {
        values.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << values[i] << '\n' << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you read files. You need to test the return value of getline.

Comment: Try `while (getline(file, value[i]))`.

Comment: So why does this answer solve the problem of missing data, is this not just a slightly cleaner way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to read in the file:

```
std::string text_line;
std::vector<string> file_lines;
while (std::getline(file, text_line))
{
  file_lines.push_back(text_line);
}
```

Although not optimal speed-wise, it gets the job done and doesn't have an upper limit (except by the amount of memory your program is allowed).

Comment: Thanks, but how does that solve the problem of missing data?